# Simple task-based OpenMP application hangs

Tags: c++, openmp

The following small program ([online version](http://rextester.com/GLBE30179)) attempts to calculate the area of a 64 by 64 square by recursively dividing into four squares until the smallest square has unit length (hardly optimal). But for some reason the program hangs. What am doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned compute( unsigned length )
{
    if( length == 1 ) return length * length;

    unsigned a[4] , area = 0 , len = length/2;

    for( unsigned i = 0; i < 4; ++i )
    {
        #pragma omp task
        {
            a[i] = compute( len );
        }

        #pragma omp single
        {
            area += a[i];
        }
    }

    return area;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned area , length = 64;

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        area = compute( length );
    }

    std::cout << area << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged your programm?

Comment: Sadly I haven't. I'm having difficulty setting up the Eclipse parallel debugger (PTP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `single` construct acts as an implicit barrier for all threads in the team. However, not all threads in the team do encounter this single block, because different threads are working at different recursion depths. This is why your application hangs.

In any case your code is not correct. After your task block, `a[i]` is not yet assigned, so you cannot immediately use it! You must wait for the task to be completed. Of course you shouldn't do that inside the loop, otherwise the tasking wouldn't exploit any parallelism. The solution is to do this at the end of the loop. Also you must specify `a` as shared for the output to become visible:

```
for( unsigned i = 0; i < 4; ++i )
{
    #pragma omp task shared(a)
    {
        a[i] = compute( len );
    }
}
#pragma omp taskwait
for( unsigned i = 0; i < 4; ++i )
{
    area += a[i];
}
```

Note that the reduction is not wrapped a `single` construct! Compute is executed by a task, so only one thread should ever have it's own local `area`. However, you need one `single` construct before you first spawn any tasks:

```
#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp single
{
    area = compute( length );
}
```

Simply speaking this opens a parallel region with a team of threads, and only one thread begins the initial computation. The other threads will pick up the tasks that are later spawned by this initial thread with the `task` construct. This is what tasking is all about.

Comment: Thanks. The program no longer hangs but I'm not getting the expected value 4096. I suspect a race condition.

Comment: You must specify `a` as shared. Sorry I missed that in my initial post. BTW: Take a look at [these slides](https://www.cs.colostate.edu/~cs475/f14/Lectures/Lec6OMPTasks.pdf). They explain tasking with a similar example.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at the slides. I've been studying OpenMP for a few weeks now and I've still got much to learn. BTW why doesn't `#pragma omp atomic area += a[i];` work in the first for loop? I wonder if its possible to get rid of the `#pragma omp taskwait` construct.

Comment: It's not possible to get rid of the `taskwait` because the result needs to be available. Otherwise it just doesn't make sense to read `a[i]`. Also make sure to understand the difference between `single`, `critical`, and `atomic`.

Comment: If I may betray my ignorance a bit, I thought everything inside the task construct was executed by a single thread sequentially.

Comment: Yes, everything inside the task construct  (except subtasks / parallel constructs) is executed by a single thread sequentially. But `area += a[i];` is outside of the task and thus can be executed by a different thread. There is a classic write-read dependency on `a[i]` between `a[i] = compute(len);` and `area += a[i];`. You could make `area` shared, and move the summation inside the thread like `tmp = compute(len); #pragma omp atomic area += tmp`. Then you need to `taskwait` before `return area;`

Comment: Thanks. Here is my updated program http://rextester.com/FUBWN84582 . Its pretty much the same expect that I've removed the array `unsigned a[4]` and replaced it with a variable of the same name inside the task construct

Answer (score 1):

Motivated by the discussion about taskwait and how it can be avoided, I show below a slightly modified version of the original code. Please note that the implied barrier at the end of the single construct is really necessary in this case.

```
unsigned tp_area = 0;
#pragma omp threadprivate(tp_area)

void compute (unsigned length)
{
  if (length == 1)
    {
      tp_area += 1;
      return;
    }

  unsigned len = length / 2;

  for (unsigned i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
#pragma omp task
      {
        compute (len);
      }
    }
}

int main ()
{
  unsigned area, length = 64;

#pragma omp parallel
  {
#pragma omp single
    {
      compute (length);
    }
#pragma omp atomic
    area += tp_area;
  }

  std::cout << area << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Quite ingenious. And apparently faster too.